# ssh2_auth_pubkey_file fails, ssh credentials succeed on command line

Tags: php, ssh, ssh-keys

From the command line this succeeds

```
ssh roybatty@192.168.xxx.xx -o 'IdentityFile ~/.ssh/transpo_rsa'
Enter passphrase for key '/home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa':
```

Using the same user, host, RSA files and passphrase in this PHP

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('192.168.xxx.xx', 22, array('hostkey'=>'ssh-rsa'));

if (ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, 'roybatty',
                          '/home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa.pub',
                          '/home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa', 'Voight_Kampff_test')) {
  echo "Public Key Authentication Successful\n";
} else {
  die('Public Key Authentication Failed');
}
```

Generates this error:

```
PHP Warning:  ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for roybatty using public key: Callback returned error in /var/www/example.com/test.php on line 12
```

I am positive the passphrase in the PHP file is the same as the one successfully used on the command line.

Per first note on the [man page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-auth-pubkey-file.php) I (earlier) deleted my first key pair and made new using

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -f transpo_rsa
```

authorized_keys was updated with the pub file contents on a newline.

On the remote machine `sudo grep 'sshd' /var/log/auth.log` gets me

sshd[550981]: Received disconnect from 192.168.yyy.yy port 41254:11: PECL/ssh2 (http://pecl.php.net/packages/ssh2) [preauth]
sshd[550981]: Disconnected from authenticating user dmartin 192.168.yyy.yy port 41254 [preauth]

**UPDATE per request**

```
roybatty@decker:/var/www/decker.example.com/signage-endpoint$ ssh -vvv roybatty@192.168.xxx.xx -o 'IdentityFile /home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa'
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.xxx.xx is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.xxx.xx [192.168.xxx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.xxx.xx:22 as 'roybatty'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/roybatty/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/roybatty/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.xxx.xx
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:oBAkI5WE0cTGkc/RsaVtBrS9K5HXIHz5upmDSmHapik
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/roybatty/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/roybatty/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.xxx.xx
debug1: Host '192.168.xxx.xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/roybatty/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa RSA SHA256:ooSv5v2ZrOfbD5AAM+3NwF+nAh3YQRwWCjPTIbL7CCE explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 53
debug3: input_userauth_banner
[snip]
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa RSA SHA256:ooSv5v2ZrOfbD5AAM+3NwF+nAh3YQRwWCjPTIbL7CCE explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa RSA SHA256:ooSv5v2ZrOfbD5AAM+3NwF+nAh3YQRwWCjPTIbL7CCE explicit
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:ooSv5v2ZrOfbD5AAM+3NwF+nAh3YQRwWCjPTIbL7CCE
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
Enter passphrase for key '/home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa':
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.xxx.xx ([192.168.xxx.xx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/roybatty/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/roybatty/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_CLASS
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env _
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Linux tyrell 5.10.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.162-1 (2023-01-21) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
You have new mail.
Last login: Fri Jul 21 14:00:18 2023 from 192.168.yyy.yy
roybatty@tyrell:~$ exit
logout
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Connection to 192.168.xxx.xx closed.
Transferred: sent 3168, received 4116 bytes, in 14.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 221.5, received 287.7
debug1: Exit status 0
roybatty@decker:/var/www/decker.example.com/signage-endpoint$ ssh -vvv roybatty@192.168.xxx.xx -o 'IdentityFile /home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa' > ~/ssh.txt
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.xxx.xx is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.xxx.xx [192.168.xxx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.xxx.xx:22 as 'roybatty'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/roybatty/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/roybatty/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.xxx.xx
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:oBAkI5WE0cTGkc/RsaVtBrS9K5HXIHz5upmDSmHapik
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/roybatty/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/roybatty/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.xxx.xx
debug1: Host '192.168.xxx.xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/roybatty/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa RSA SHA256:ooSv5v2ZrOfbD5AAM+3NwF+nAh3YQRwWCjPTIbL7CCE explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 53
debug3: input_userauth_banner
[snip]
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa RSA SHA256:ooSv5v2ZrOfbD5AAM+3NwF+nAh3YQRwWCjPTIbL7CCE explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa RSA SHA256:ooSv5v2ZrOfbD5AAM+3NwF+nAh3YQRwWCjPTIbL7CCE explicit
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:ooSv5v2ZrOfbD5AAM+3NwF+nAh3YQRwWCjPTIbL7CCE
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
Enter passphrase for key '/home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa':
debug2: bad passphrase given, try again...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/roybatty/.ssh/transpo_rsa':
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.xxx.xx ([192.168.xxx.xx]:22).
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/roybatty/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/roybatty/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_CLASS
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env _
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
debug3: send packet: type 100
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
debug3: send packet: type 100
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
debug3: send packet: type 100
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1)
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Connection to 192.168.xxx.xx closed.
Transferred: sent 3288, received 4792 bytes, in 214.6 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 15.3, received 22.3
debug1: Exit status 130
```

What should my next debugging move be?

Comment: Pot an output of `ssh -vvv ...` + What version of PHP SSH2 are you using? Does it support sha2?

Comment: I don't normally post "try this library" comments, but whenever I need to deal with PHP and SSH I immediately turn to [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.com/docs/connect) and never bother with core. Not that core is bad or wrong, either, I've just found it so much easier to debug things with this.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  output is OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022     libssh2 is 1.8.0   not sure re SHA support

Comment: I've meant a complete output of `ssh -vvv roybatty@192.168.xxx.xx -o 'IdentityFile ~/.ssh/transpo_rsa'`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl full output added.  Sorry for confusion

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ssh -vvv full output added. Sorry for confusion